# Combining sticky navigation and transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress site utilizing Bootstrap navigation. I have the navigation below my logo/brand. I want to have the navigation 'stick' to the top of the screen when the user scrolls to it. Once the navigation is 'stuck' to the top i want its height to animate larger.

I have working code for both separately but not sure how to combine them to achieve what I want.

HTML - scale navigation

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 25;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
  if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
       $('header').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('header').removeClass('shrink');
    }
 });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  });
</script>
```

HTML - sticky script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $("#divname");
var pos = s.position();                    
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

HTML - header.php

```
    <a class="brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"></a>

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button> 

    </div>  

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

...
```

CSS

```
header {
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 padding: 0 25px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
 -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease, padding 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease, padding 0.35s ease;
 -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease, padding 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.35s ease, padding 0.35s ease;
 transition: height 0.35s ease, padding 0.35s ease;
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it

Comment: Unfortunately the amount of variables involved I can't. I was wondering if someone had done something similar and had suggestions

Comment: try to call $('header').addClass('shrink'); after you add the class s.addClass("stick"); and vice versa if i am getting you right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to accomplish this results, you need to look into [`.navbar-fixed-top`](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). Bootstrap make the navbar sticky with this class. Here an example:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var navbar = $('#navbar');

        // if win >= navbar and not already a sticky
        if (windowpos >= navbar.position().top && !navbar.hasClass("navbar-fixed-top") ) {
            navbar.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");

        // if win <= navbar and is a sticky
        } else if( windowpos <= navbar.position().top && navbar.hasClass("navbar-fixed-top")  ) {
            navbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color:orange;
    padding:5px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

#navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
```

This increase the padding, but as `transition: all` is set any css variable will do just fine. This is example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/w5j8dmkf/) without bootstrap!